# Number Pad not showing swift 4

Tags: ios12, numpad, swift4.2

I am doing a side project , just to implement some UI objects and see if i can do simple programming..

i have put a uilable, a textfield and a button.. the objective is to enter numbers in the textfield and display it on the lable when pressing the button.. i have selected the number keyboard for input.. as am only interested in entering numbers..and using the iPhone 8 simulator... i am using macOS Mojave 10.14, xcode 10.1, swift 4.2 ...

on run , strange things happing.. number pad keyboard does not  compe up! and text field doesnt take in put , even from the laptop keyboard...

error message:

2018-11-08 12:11:51.910752+0300 QPages 3[4250:186019] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

2018-11-08 12:11:54.219190+0300 QPages 3[4250:186019] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/mohamedabousaif/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B0D8741-BDE6-4F62-900D-E52DE7B4D27C/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

2018-11-08 12:11:54.220103+0300 QPages 3[4250:186019] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

2018-11-08 12:11:54.289740+0300 QPages 3[4250:186019] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 20603_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

2018-11-08 12:11:55.532774+0300 QPages 3[4250:186137] [MC] Invalidating cache

can anybody help please ..

Thanks .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An8xr.png)

Comment: And in simulator, you have tried `cmd + shift + k` to toggle show/hide keyboard?

Comment: follow up to the above subject, i have side loaded my proejct to my iPhone, and i found the number pad working normal on the actuall phone! which is good news , but still cannt get it working on the simulator in xcode... i thought i will update you with this ..

Comment: Hello Jake G, its working , cmd+shift+k .... thanks for your suggestion ..please explain what is happing... cheers

Comment: Great. `cmd+k` toggles show/hide the software keyboard. `cmd+shift+k` toggles connecting your hardware (mac) keyboard to the simulator. If you open Simulator and go to Hardware > Keyboard menu you'll find these options.